# Diagonal matrix check returns true for both non diagonal and diagonal

Tags: java

I am not sure where logically I am wrong. It returns true for both diagonal and non diagonal matrix. I am still new to 2d array and have watched video and read online. I do understand on how 2d array work but I am unable get the correct answer.

```
..
else{
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            if((i != j) && (matrix[i][j] != 0)){
                isDyg = false;
            }

        }
        //System.out.print("");
    }
    isDyg = true;
}
return isDyg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after your loop ends, isDyg is set to true everytime.

Change `isDyg = false;` to `return false;`

Or change your code to -

```
        isDyg = true; 
        outerloop:    
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                if((i != j) && (matrix[i][j] != 0)){
                    isDyg = false;
                    break outerloop;
                }

            }
            //System.out.print("");
        }
        return isDyg;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Also is there a way I can get rid off `isDyg == true` at the end?

Comment: added suggestion for that too